# Importing a csv file to sqllite3 using python functional programming

Tags: python, csv, import, sqlite

I know there are some other posts out there, but I was not able to find the specific question I had in mind. 
I'm using US_baby_names csv file. and want to import this csv file line by line into sqlite3 as a table.

I'm able to create the table called storage.
I'm then trying to read lines in the csv file and put it into that table, but I must be doing something wrong.

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from sqlite3 import Error
import csv

def CreateConnection ( dbFileName ):
   try:
      conn = sql.connect(dbFileName)
      return conn
   except Error as e:
      print(e)

   return None

def CreateNew( dbConnection, new):
     sql =  """INSERT INTO storage (dat, Id, Name, Year, group, subgroup, Count)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"""

     try:
       cursor = dbConnection.cursor()
       cursor.execute(sql, new)
       return cursor.lastrowid
     except Error as e:
       print(e)

def Main():
  database = "storage.db"
  dbConnection = CreateConnection(database)

  with open('storage.csv', 'rb') as fin:
     dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
     to_db = [(i['dat'], i['Id'], i['Name'], i['Year'], i['group'], i['subgroup'], i['Count']) \
        for i in dr]

    cursor.executemany(CreateNew(sql, to_db))

    dbConnection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Main()
```

I believe my cursor.executemany is wrong, but I'm not able to figure out what else to do..

Thanks

Comment: Using a function to open a database connection and return the connection is a bad idea. Use a context manager. You're passing a function that executes a database transaction to executemany, which isn't going to work at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right with much of your code, but:

- in `cursor.execute(sql, new)` you are passing an iterable, `new`, to `sqlite3.execute()` (which requires a simple SQL statement), instead of `sqlite3.executemany()`.
- Moreover, the result of `CreateNew()` is an integer, `lastrowid`, and you pass that result to `executemany()`.
- You must use `Connection.commit()` to save the changes to the database, and `Connection.rollback()` to discard them.
- You must open the file for the `csv.DictReader` class as a **text file**, in `r` or `rt` mode.
- Finally, remember that `sqlite3.Connection` is a context manager, so you can use it in a `with` statement.

This should be your desired outcome:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from sqlite3 import Error
import csv


def create_table(conn):
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS baby_names("\
        "dat TEXT,"\
        "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"\
        "Name TEXT NOT NULL,"\
        "Year INTEGER NOT NULL,"\
        "Gender TEXT NOT NULL,"\
        "State TEXT NOT NULL,"\
        "Count INTEGER)"

    conn.execute(sql)
    conn.execute("DELETE FROM baby_names")

def select_all(conn):
    for r in conn.execute("SELECT * FROM baby_names").fetchall():
        print(r)


def execute_sql_statement(conn, data):
    sql = "INSERT INTO baby_names "\
        "(dat, Id, Name, Year, Gender, State, Count) "\
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    try:
        cursor = conn.executemany(sql, data)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
        conn.rollback()
        return None
    else:
        conn.commit()
        return cursor.lastrowid

def main():        
    with sql.connect('baby_names.db') as conn, open('US_Baby_Names_right.csv', 'r') as fin:
        create_table(conn)

        dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
        data = [(i['dat'], i['Id'], i['Name'], i['Year'], i['Gender'], i['State'], i['Count']) for i in dr ]

        lastrowid = execute_sql_statement(conn, data)

        select_all(conn)


main()
```

I added a `create_table()` function just to test my code. I also made up a sample test file as follows:

```
dat,Id,Name,Year,Gender,State,Count
1,1,John,1998,M,Washington,2
2,2,Luke,2000,M,Arkansas,10
3,3,Carrie,1999,F,Texas,3
```

The output of the `select_all()` function is:

```
('1',1,'John',1998,'M','Washington',2)
('2',2,'Luke',2000,'M','Arkansas',10)
('3',3,'Carrie',1999,'F','Texas',3)
```

Comment: Thank you, your comments made it easy to see my mistakes! I really appreciate it